# How to store data with an array?

Tags: php, arrays

people. I need some help.

I was trying to create a form in html, and there's a section with a "valuation" type "radio button".

This one:

```
<input type='radio' value='muy mala' name='val'>Muy mala
<input type='radio' value='mala' name='val'>Mala 
<input type='radio' value='media' name='val'>Media 
<input type='radio' value='buena' name='val'>Buena 
<input type='radio' value='muy buena' name='val'>Muy buena
```

I need to save and store that info with an array in a new file and then show it; but I'm a begginer with PHP and I don't know how to do it.

Comment: He might want to say data

Comment: Why do you need to store it in an array? Arrays are used when you have multiple items of the same type, but a radio button just has a single choice.

Comment: When you post the form, the value of the chosen button will be in `$_POST['val']`. What more do you need to know to use it?

Comment: Sorry. My mistake.

Comment: About the question, so it's that simple? I don't know how to use $_POST correctly. I'm used to work with "if, elseif and else", and it's because of that I used it so far. But It was today when I knew about $_POST and $_GET.

Comment: @ilos28 It sounds like you really need to read a tutorial on how to process forms with PHP. It should explain all the details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the form is submitted by the user, the form's values will be available in `$_POST` or `$_GET` depending on the form's action method. If you want to access the value in your example, simply use `$_POST['val']`. There will not be more than one value since a radio button forces a single choice among multiple options.

Comment: Thank you so much.